# Javascript: display an alert when a form is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I have created a simple web app that has 2 form selections, when the user makes their selection from each I want an `alert` to display showing them the choices they made.

I have attempted this below but when both forms are checked the alert is **not** displayed. What am I missing? Note see the comment:

```
 //BELOW IS NOT BEING DISPLAYED BUT SHOULD BE
```

**Current code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Calculator</h1>

<p>Select the importance of this:</p>

<form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Severity" value="negligible"> Negligible<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Severity" value="minor"> Minor<br>
</form>

<p>Select the Probability of this:</p>

<form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Probability" value="improbable"> Improbable<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Probability" value="remote"> Remote<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Probability" value="occasional"> Occasional<br>

<button onclick= "analyseThis()"> Analyse this </button> <br>



<script>

function analyseThis(){

    var severities = document.getElementsByName('Severity');
   var probs = document.getElementsByName('Probability');

  var severity = undefined;
  for(var i = 0; i < ages.length; i++)
  {
    if(severities[i].checked)
    {
      age = severities[i].value;

    }
  }

   var probability = undefined;
   for(var i = 0; i < probs.length; i++)
   {
      if(probs[i].checked)
      {
        probability = probs[i].value;

      }
    }

   //BELOW IS NOT BEING DISPLAYED BUT SHOULD BE
   alert("Severity is: " + age + "Probability is: " + probability);

}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use JQuery to validate the form and submit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery and use the click function of the button to submit.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("{form id/class button id/class OR button id/class}").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //perform validation

        //if everything is good...
        $("{form id/class}").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something funny is happening:

1. Your function analyseThis() *does* get called, but there is an
   error when it is being evaluated.
2. The form on the page is being "submitted", so the page reloads
   and you never see the error.

To prevent the page from reloading (so you can see your error) do this:

1. Pass in the `event` object to your analyseThis() function from the `onclick` hander:

   ```
   <button onclick= "analyseThis(event)"> Analyse this </button>
   ```
2. Make your analyseThis() accept the event object, and call .preventDefault() on it so that the page doesn't reload:

   ```
   function analyseThis(e){
     e.preventDefault()
     // the rest of your function body here....
   }
   ```

After you do that, you will see the underlying error output in the console:

```
ReferenceError: ages is not defined (line 33, col 17)
for(var i = 0; i < ages.length; i++)
```

If you do want the form to be submitted, just remember to remove the `e.preventDefault()` call after debugging the code.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this error (now reffering to correct array) but the alert box is still not showing

Comment: Are there any other errors displayed in the browser console (you can press F12 to bring the console up)?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code - you are checking `ages.length` in your loop which is probably undefined (no `ages` variable in your code) in the first loop and your code execution should stop there.

Working JSBin code here:
http://jsbin.com/yelihugune/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < ages.length; i++)
{
    if(severities[i].checked)
    {
        age = severities[i].value;

    }
}
```

'ages' is not yet defined in your code, nor is 'age'. This will be throwing an error, stopping your code from running. This is why the alert is not going.

Declare the ages array.